# Example of const pointer to a constant value

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand that in c++ we can have a constant pointer to a constant value:

```
const int value{ 5 };
const int* const ptr{ &value };
```

This means:

- the memory address held by `ptr` cannot be changed.
- we cannot use indirection via `ptr` to change `value`

When would such a pointer be useful?

Comment: It seems like your "This means:" list answers the question?  Many developers prefer immutable variables over mutable variables, and pointers have two "levels" of mutability.

Comment: Pointers are useful for achieving indirection.

Comment: It would be useful when you want a function to have a read-only access to some data.

Comment: Your two statements concerning the meaning are right, but it's missing a third: the value of `ptr` cannot be changed either. At least, that's the case when I take the "address held by `ptr`" as the address that the pointer points to, not the pointer's address itself.

Answer (score 6):

You could e.g. store the position after the end when of an array when iterating using a pointer. This can be useful to avoid accidentally modifying the pointer in a loop that is more complex than the one below. If in addition to that you don't want the array to be modifiable, you'll also make the element type const; this leads to a const pointer to a const element being useful:

```
void printArray(int const* array, size_t count)
{
    int const* pos = array;
    int const* const end = array + count; // end is the pointer past the count-th element of array

    while(pos != end)
    {
        std::cout << *pos << std::endl;
        ++pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all data needs to be changed in every context. For example, you might want to write a function that does some aggregate analysis on a large chunk of data. You don't need to modify it to compute things about it, so in that case it would make sense to pass that kind of pointer as a parameter.